# How to open ftps path using fopen in php; Did not receive identification string from

Tags: php, fopen, ftps

I'm trying to push string data to a remote ftp path. I've done this before in other settings, but in this case the server doesn't seem to recognize the identification string. This is probably just a small syntax error on the ftp path string, but I can't see it.

I know that I'm reaching the remote server because I can check the log file and see the message

```
Did not receive identification string from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

for each attempt that I make.

After hanging for a while my script simply returns the error

```
Warning: fopen() failed to open stream.
```

My file path is formatted thusly:

```
$ftp_path = "ftps://user:password@remoteaddress:12345/path/to/file/filename.txt";//port 12345 is deliberate because I use port forwarding on the server to reduce failed hack attempts
```

The part of the script that deals with the connection is as follows:

```
$ftp_path = "ftps://user:password@remoteaddress:12345/path/to/file/filename.txt";
// Allow/disallow overwriting of existing files on the remote FTP server
$stream_options = array('ftps' => array('overwrite' => false));
// Creates a stream context resource with the defined options
$stream_context = stream_context_create($stream_options);
// Opens the file for writing and truncates it to zero length 
if ($fh = fopen($ftp_path, 'w', 0, $stream_context)){
    // Writes contents to the file
    if(fputs($fh, $content)){
        echo "records pushed successfully.";
    } else {
        echo "The stream was opened, but the records failed to push.";
    }
    // Closes the file handle
    fclose($fh);
} else {
    die('Could not open remote ftp.');
}
```

Comment: Does filename.txt exist?  Does path/to/file exist?  Are you able to create path/to/file/filename.txt outside of PHP?

Comment: The path exists. The file does not exist. I'm able to create it outside of php using ftp and ssh. The fact that the remote server is logging the attempt means I'm reaching it. The fact that it says "Did not receive identification string" means to me that the user:password@remoteaddress part of the path must be wrong somehow, but I don't know how.

Comment: ftps is not the same as sftp, it does not use SSH.

Comment: Thank you Devon. That is exactly the right answer. If you want to make it an answer I would mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may indicate you are attempting to access an SFTP/SSH server through the FTP wrapper.  FTP/FTPS and SSH/SFTP are not compatible protocols so don't confuse FTPS with SFTP.